# Question regarding to Reactjs and Django, the use of serializer in django-rest-framework

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a question regarding to the serializer from Django-rest-framework and Reactjs. My question is that can the serializer work itself without the django model? since I don't need to save anything in database. I just want to do post request to backend, and it will take the data and run the ML model, and show the result back to frontend. After that the record will be cleared. Will it be possible to do so without using model? Can I only save serializer instance and give a get request to show it in the frontend?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes it's possible, you can just use non-model [serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#declaring-serializers). But about the saving part, what object are you trying to create/save?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What I intend to do is after I post the data to the backend and run the ML model, I want to show the results like accuracy, training size or test size etc. back to frontend.As far as I know, these should be save as json type so that I can get it from frontend, but can it be done without using model?

Comment: I've searched the documentation and I saw there is a save function for serializer (serializer.save()), is it used to save the serializer instance withiut saving it into model?

Comment: @HooLouis No, `save()` calls either `create` or `update`. It depends on the data you pass to the serializer. For instance, `MySerializer(instance=my_model_instance, data=my_new_data).save()` invokes `update()` and `MySerializer(data=my_new_data).save()` invokes `create()`. You can pass extra data to `save()` and add them to `validated_data` if `create()` or `update` is being invoked by `save()`.

Comment: Okay, understood!

Comment: @HooLouis There is no need to use a serializer at all if you dont´t want to update/create objects. If you want to use a serializer to validate your data without saving and updating, you can invoke `serializer.is_valid()` and that´s all.

Comment: If I want to create a non-model serializer, how should I define the 'GET' request function? Since there are no model objects I can call... Or should I say that non-model serializer will not have the 'GET' method

Comment: I am confused on how should I bring the result back to front... Since after the model complete running, I will want to show the accuracy and other parameters back to front, will it be possible to work without using model?

Comment: The response of post provides your new content you want to display. For instance `def post(request): return Response({'accuracy': 2, 'parameters': [] })`

Answer (score 0):

```
serializer = MyModelSerializer(myObject)
```

You can then get the data with:

```
serializer.data
```